# Why is my display function not running C++ Structs Matrix Transpose?

Tags: c++, matrix, struct

My program is about taking the transpose of a matrix and displaying it, using structs. I'm using pointer to structs in each function, just for practice although I could've done it by simply passing the struct or by reference. The program is working fine until function inputMatrix. The program takes input and then finishes executing without any output.

What I know for sure is the **problem** is in **display function** or **structure trans** I'm creating in main(which has the final result).

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Matrix
{
    int **data;
    int rows;
    int columns;
};

void createMatrix(Matrix *mat)
{
    mat->data = new int *[mat->rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->columns; i++)
    {
        mat->data[i] = new int[mat->columns];
    }
}

void inputMatrix(Matrix *mat)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat->columns; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter element of row " << i + 1 << " and column " << j + 1<<endl;
            cin >> mat->data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
Matrix transpose(Matrix* mat)
{
    Matrix transpose;
    transpose.rows = mat->rows;
    transpose.columns = mat->columns;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<mat->columns;j++)
        {
            transpose.data[i][j] = mat->data[j][i];
        }
    }
    return transpose;
}

void display(Matrix* mat)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<mat->rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<mat->columns;j++)
        {
            cout<<setw(3)<<mat->data[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Matrix mat;
    cout<<"Enter the rows of matrix: \n";
    cin>>mat.rows;
    cout<<"\nEnter the columns of matrix: \n";
    cin>>mat.columns;

    createMatrix(&mat);
    inputMatrix(&mat);
    cout<<endl;
    Matrix trans = transpose(&mat);
    display(&trans);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your function `transpose`, where do you allocate space for `transpose.data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in function transpose, I needed to allocate memory to `Matrix transpose`
The code is below:

```
Matrix transpose(Matrix* mat)
{
    Matrix transpose;
    transpose.rows = mat->rows;
    transpose.columns = mat->columns;
    
    createMatrix(&transpose);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->columns;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<mat->rows;j++)
        {
            transpose.data[i][j] = mat->data[j][i];
        }
    }
    return transpose;
}
```